# Sitecore 9 httpBeginRequest pipeline reuse?

Tags: best-practices, pipelines, session-state

In my content delivery instance I have user information that is used in multiple *componentized* view renderings, which is sourced from  REST services (some of this I want to pre-fill, some will be done via AJAX calls).

I was attempting to write a Sitecore pipeline processor which validates that the user is authenticated - then uses their authentication token to pre-load some of that information so it's available in the User Profile (or in Session).  *My idea was eventually to make some of this basic information available for the content editors to add via personalization rules and tokens.*

I tried patching it at the end of **httpBeginRequest** - but this appears to only fire for the initial request (the processor does not fire hitting refresh on the page).  Is this a caching issue or because it's a singleton. I did add **reusable="false"** to my patching config but this does not appear to make a difference.

Note - I also looked at **httpRequestProcessed** - but this appears to fire AFTER the page has already rendered - which I think would make it useless for what I'm trying to do.

Also - feel free to suggest I'm just not using the pipeline appropriately :)

Processor skeleton...

```
  public class ServiceCachingProcessor : HttpRequestProcessor
{

    public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {


        try
        {
            if (!Sitecore.Context.User.IsAuthenticated || Sitecore.Context.User.Identity == null)
            {
                Log.Warn("User not authenticated / Identity unavailable", this);
                return;
            }

            var identity = Sitecore.Context.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            var tokenClaim = identity.Claims.First(x => x.Type.Contains("OAuthToken"));

            /// use token to pull service information if session empty
            if(Session[cachedInfo] == null) {
            ...
            }


        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post up the (skeleton) code of your processor, the `httpBeginRequest` pipeline is called once for every request. Are you using MVC, cos you may need to patch before MVC Transfer processors. If you are storing the user info in session, I would question putting this logic in a httpRequestBegin processor though, unless you really want to be checking the data against the external service every request (which seems a little crazy)

Comment: Thanks - I will.  i was planning on just checking to see if the cached data existed first - so going to the service only if it had expired or empty.

Comment: @jammykam - I agree with your questioning putting this in httpRequestBegin but is httpRequestProcessed too late?  I am utilizing MVC (mostly view renderings).

Comment: `httpRequestProcessed` will be too late for sure. Suggest you move your processor earlier in the `httpRequestPipeline`, maybe try `patch:before="*[Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.HttpRequest.TransferRoutedRequest, Sitecore.Mvc]"` instead.